# When a usercontrol layout gets updated, dynamic rows in fixed grid are squished

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid in xaml:

I create dynamically a number of rows:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= numHorizLines - 1; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
            r.Height = new GridLength(Convert.ToDouble(size), GridUnitType.Star);
            gVertNums.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
        }
```

When the usercontrol's layout_updated event fires, I execute the loop to recreate the number of rows based on the height of the control (after clearing everything in the gVertNums grid).  And I add textblocks to the grid rows with numbers in them (leaving that code out for simplicity).

This works nicely when the main window first opens.  However when the layout_updated event fires again, the gVertNums displays the correct number of rows but they are squished.

It seems like something is going on with the grid height thus causing the rows to be squished.  Even though I reset the gVertNums.height to be the height of the new layout, the rows are smushed...

Here is a screen shot of main window open:

[image: on main window open]

Here is a screen shot when the usercontrol gets resized:

[image: after usercontrol is resized]

In this example, the grid width is changed but the height is not and the rows still get squeezed together.  The spacing is "size" (which is 25 pixels).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have no (shown) code that is clearing the `RowDefinitions`. So after adding them in again, you probably now have double the number of rows that you would expect.

Try this

```
gVertNums.RowDefinitions.Clear();
for (int i = 1; i <= numHorizLines - 1; i++)
    {
        RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
        r.Height = new GridLength(Convert.ToDouble(size), GridUnitType.Star);
        gVertNums.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
    }
```

Comment: This worked!  I was doing a gVertNums.Children.Clear() but apparently that did not clear the row definitions.  I am obliged to you!